# search for data in a table in laravel

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

im trying to search for name or id of students in the table but i do not know how to do that with router and controller. I already have the table and search form with button i need the list to show all data initially then display only the entered data when a name is searched

here is my search form

```
<!-- Search form -->
    <form class="d-flex align-items-center flex-nowrap" action="/search">
  <input name="q" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Search</button>
</form>
```

and this is the table

```
<table class="table">

  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">id</th>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>          
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $student->cne }}</td>
      <td>{{ $student->firstName }}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{ url('/edit/'.$student->id )}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would love the realtime search thingy so I can get rid of the search button lol
thank you

Comment: Hi Fathi, show us the controller for this please.

Also the real time searching would require some javascript.
Checkout Livewire to do this maybe.

Comment: hi @RachidS, I did not make the controller for the search. I will search for Livewire

Comment: I'd suggest Livewire especially if you need that kind of feature here and there.

Here is a documentation page for the exact thing you want to do : https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/query-string

And if you want to go further, there are great courses on Laracasts or some free in youtube: https://youtu.be/HWTF-oi70e4

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (without the realtime thingy, check my comment for that)

In your controller that returns your students, you can grab the request and if it has a `q` parameter then you can filter your query.

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $students = Student::query();

    if($request->has("q") {
        $students->where("cne", $request->get("q"))
            ->orWhere("firstName", $request->get("q")
    }

    return view("students.index", [
        "students" => $students->get();
    ]);
}
```

You can use a `LIKE` operator if you'd prefer.